# Get all users who commented on a facebook post of my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the users who replied in a comment of my page.

I tried with different access tokens and I keep getting only the
`created_time`, `message` and `id`

I tried adding a `?fields=from` but that returned only the `id`

Doing the same on a specific comment also return the same results

Comment: did you try with a page token of that page?

Comment: @luschn Yes, I also added all possible permissions, at least I believe I have. I'm using the Graph API explorer and selected all `Events Group Pages` and `User Data Permissions` in the Permissions Options

Comment: it is quite possible that this is not possible at all anymore, for privacy reasons you should not get user data of users who did not authorize your app anyway.

Comment: it is quite possible that this is not possible at all anymore, for privacy reasons you should not get user data of users who did not authorize your app anyway.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but since you can practically get all of those by simply running a javascript on the page of the post, as well as it is publicly available even to all users, I don't see how that could be a privacy issue

Comment: well, that would not be allowed anyway, facebook forbids scraping. and just because something is public does not mean you are allowed to grab it with an app.

Comment: According to documentation this should still be possible (_“For any comments or replies owned by (on) a Page, you must use a Page access token if you want User information to be included in the response.”_), but I have seen countless questions here and bug reports in the FB dev area that suggest otherwise.

Comment: So, I'll guess I'll find some "hacky" way for now...?